# Cell image in uitableview shows back up when scrolling

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimageview, uiimage

I'm doing the following to set the cell image if a message is unread

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MessageCell"];

        Message *m = [self.messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        cell.textLabel.text = m.subject;
        NSString *detail = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %@", m.callbackName, m.dateSent];
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = detail;

        if([m.messageRead isEqualToString:@"False"])
            cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"new.png"];


    return cell;
}
```

This is correctly showing an image when it's supposed to.  If I scroll down however and scroll back up, they all show the image whether it's supposed to or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cells are reused. So you need to set each property for every condition.

```
if([m.messageRead isEqualToString:@"False"])
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"new.png"];
else
    cell.imageView.image = nil;
```

Comment: Ah, I guess I never put those two together.

Answer (score 1):

Since `UITableViewCell`s are reused, you should set `cell.imageView.image` to `nil` in case you do not need image.

```
if([m.messageRead isEqualToString:@"False"]) {
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"new.png"];
} else {
    cell.imageView.image = nil;
}
```